# What is the 'realtime' process priority setting for

Tags: windows, process

From what I've read in the past, you're encouraged not to change the priority of your windows applications programmatically, and if you do, you should never change them to 'realtime'.

What does the 'realtime' process priority setting do, compared to 'High', and 'Above Normal'?

My Processor is an i7 4710 HQ 2.50GHz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in [Scheduling Priorities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN (emphasis mine):

> You should almost never use REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS, because this interrupts system threads that manage mouse input, keyboard input, and background disk flushing. **This class can be appropriate for applications that "talk" directly to hardware or that perform brief tasks that should have limited interruptions.**

So that's the theory.  In practice, if you need to do this, you're probably doing something wrong.